# Show that $\det(\mathrm{adj}(A)) = \det(A)^3$ for a $(4 \times 4)$-matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> Let $A_{ik}$ be the cofactor of $a_{ik}$
>    in the determinant 
>   $$d = \left|
> \begin{matrix}
>  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\ 
>  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
>  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
>  a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\ 
> \end{matrix}
> \right|.$$
>   Let $D$ be the corresponding determinant with $a_{ik}$ replaced by $A_{ik}.$ Prove $D = d^3.$

**Book solution**

Let $\alpha$ be the matrix of the given determinant with elements $a_{ik}$ and let $\beta$ be the matrix of the cofactors $A_{ik},$ and let $\gamma$ be the transpose of $\beta.$ Then the product matrix $\alpha \gamma$ is a diagonal matrix with all entries on the main diagonal equal to $d$.

Thus, $\det{\alpha \gamma} = d^4 = (\det{\alpha}) (\det{\gamma}) = (\det{\alpha})(\det{\beta}) = dD.$ The equation $$dD = d^4 \tag{1}$$
is an identity between polynomials in the $16$ matrix entries regard as independent determinants. Since there certainly exists a $4 \times 4$ matrix whose determinant is not zero, $d$ is non-zero in the polynomial ring. Since the polynomial ring is an integral domain, the result $$D = d^3$$
follows from $(1)$.

**My questions**

How is $\alpha \gamma$
 a diagonal matrix with all entries on the main diagonal equal to $d$? Does this come from some linear algebra rule? Then how did they get $(\det{\alpha}) (\det{\gamma}) = (\det{\alpha})(\det{\beta}) = dD$? Does $AA^{T} = AA$? Finally I am not really understanding the last paragraph so if someone could explain that that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### General Solution

Let $K$ be our ground field and $L = K(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44})$ the field of rational functions in the 16 variables $x_{ij}$ with $1 \leq i,j \leq 4$. We will work over $L$ instead of $K$ from the very start, to avoid confusion and the taste of handwaving at later points.

---

We slightly change the definitions, to make everything work, but still see how this applies to the exercise: Let $\alpha \in \mathrm{M}(4 \times 4, L)$ be defined as
$$
 \alpha = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} \\ 
  x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} \\
  x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} \\
  x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44} \\ 
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let $\beta$ be the adjugate matrix of $\alpha$, i.e. the $(i,j)$-the entry of $\beta$ is the $(i,j)$-th cofactor of $\alpha$, and let $\gamma = \beta^T$. Let $d = \det \alpha$ and $D = \det \beta$. Notice that by Leibniz’ formula the entries of $d$ and $D$ are polynomials in the variables $x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}$. For example
\begin{align*}
 d
 &=
 \left|
  \begin{matrix}
  x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} \\ 
  x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} \\
  x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} \\
  x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44} \\ 
  \end{matrix}
 \right| \\
 &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_4} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) x_{1\sigma(1)} x_{2\sigma(2)} x_{3\sigma(3)} x_{4\sigma(4)}.
\end{align*}
is a polynomial of degree $4$ (notice that the monomials $x_{1\sigma(1)} x_{2\sigma(2)} x_{3\sigma(3)} x_{4\sigma(4)}$ with $\sigma \in S_4$ are pairwise different and thus cannot cancel out). In particular $d \neq 0$.

---

First notice that
$$
 (\alpha \gamma)_{ik}
 = \left( \alpha \beta^T \right)_{ik}
 = \sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_{ij} \beta^T_{jk}
 = \sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_{ij} \beta_{kj}.
$$
For $i = k$ this is just the expansion of $\alpha \gamma$ by its $k$-th row. Thus the diagonal entries of $\alpha \gamma$ are $\det \alpha = d$.

For $i \neq k$ consider the matrix $\alpha^{(k)}$, where we replace the $k$-th row of $\alpha$ by its $i$-th row. Then the $i$-th and $k$-th rows of $\alpha^{(k)}$ coincide, so $\det \alpha^{(k)} = 0$. Expanding $\alpha^{(k)}$ by its $k$-th row yields the right hand side of the above formula. So the non-diagonal entries of $\alpha \gamma$ are zero.

Now $\alpha \gamma$ is a diagonal matrix, so $\det(\alpha \gamma)$ is just the product of the diagonal entries, all four of which are $d$. Thus $\det(\alpha \gamma) = d^4$.

That $(\det \alpha)(\det \gamma) = (\det \alpha)(\det \beta)$ follows from $\det \gamma = \det \beta^T = \det \beta$, which follows from the determinant being invariant under transposition. That $(\det \alpha)(\det \beta) = dD$ follows from the definitions of $d$ and $D$.

For the last paragraph: We have now shown that $d^4 = dD$. Because $d \neq 0$ we can divide by $d$ (which is a unit in the field $L$ we are working over) to get $d^3 = D$. Evaluating this at $a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44} \in K$ gives
$$
 d^3(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44}) = D(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44}),
$$
which is what we wanted to show in the first place.

---

#### Over infinite fields

If our ground field $K$ is infinite, we can also argue without using the field of rational functions. Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $d$ and $D$ be defined as originally, i.e. as in the books solution.

We still get in the same way that $\alpha \gamma$ is diagonal with all diagonal entries $d$, and thus $\det \alpha = d^4$, and that $(\det \alpha) (\det \gamma) = (\det \alpha)(\det \beta) = dD$. So $d^4 = dD$.

For the last paragraph we argue simlilary to the general case: Consider the following polynomials in the 16 variables $x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{13}, x_{14}, x_{21}, \dotsc, x_{44}$, i.e. elements of the polynomial ring $K[x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}]$:
\begin{align*}
 p(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44})
 &=
 \left|
  \begin{matrix}
  x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} \\ 
  x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} \\
  x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} \\
  x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44} \\ 
  \end{matrix}
 \right| \\
 &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_4} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) x_{1\sigma(1)} x_{2\sigma(2)} x_{3\sigma(3)} x_{4\sigma(4)}.
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
  &\, q(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}) \\
 =&\,
 \left|
  \begin{matrix}
  y_{11}(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}) & \cdots & y_{14}(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}) \\ 
  \vdots                         & \ddots & \vdots                         \\
  y_{41}(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}) & \cdots & y_{44}(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}) 
  \end{matrix}
 \right| \\
 =&\, \sum_{\sigma \in S_4} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)
      y_{1\sigma(1)}(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}) \dotsm y_{4\sigma(4)}(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}).
\end{align*}
where for all $1 \leq i,j \leq 4$ we define $y_{ij}(x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44})$ to be the $(i,j)$-th cofactor of the matrix.
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} \\ 
  x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} \\
  x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} \\
  x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44} \\ 
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

By definition of $p$ and $q$ we have
$$
 d = p(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44})
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 D = q(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44}).
$$
Therefore we have shown so far that
$$
 p(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44})q(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44}) = p^4(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44})
$$
for all $a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44} \in K$. So the polynomial $p^4-pq = p(p^3-q)$ evaluates zero everywhere. **If our field is infinite** we can now follows that already $p(p^3-q) = 0$, i.e. not only evaluates $p(p^3-q)$ zero everywhere, but it is already the zero polynomial.

But we can find $b_{11}, \dotsc, b_{44}$ such that $p(b_{11}, \dotsc, b_{44}) \neq 0$ (i.e. the ($4 \times 4$)-matrix with entries $b_{ij}$ is invertible). So $p \neq 0$. Because the polynomial ring $K[x_{11}, \dotsc, x_{44}]$ is an integral domain we can follow from $p \neq 0$ and $p(p^3-q) = 0$ that already $p^3 - q = 0$, i.e. $p^3 = q$. Evaluating these polynomials, we get that
$$
 d^3 = p^3(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44}) = q(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44}) = D
$$
for all $a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{44} \in K$, which is what we wanted to prove in the first place.

---

PS: Also notice that in the same way(s) we can show that for every $n \times n$ square matrix $A$ we have
$$
 \det(\mathrm{adj}(A)) = \det(A)^{n-1},
$$
where $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ denotes the adjugate of $A$.